# Playing with Gooey effect with SVG

Tags: html, css, animation, svg

I'm currently trying to recreate Gooey effect with SVG Filter. I have 2 circles and I want the effect affects on that 2 circles but I cannot figure out what's the problem in this example. Please help me with it. Here is my code:

```css
body {
  filter: url('#goo')
}
.circle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #E63946;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.circle-1 {
  left: 12%;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle circle-1"></div>
<div class="circle circle-2"></div>
<svg>
  <defs>
    <filter id="goo">
      <feGuassianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="5" result="gaussianBlur"></feGuassianBlur>
      <feColorMatrix in="gaussianBlur" type='matrix' 
                     values="1 0 0 0 0
                             0 1 0 0 0
                             0 0 1 0 0
                             0 0 0 12 -6" result="color-matrix" />
      <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="color-matrix" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: feGuassianBlur is a typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/359h9m5m/1/

You have a typo, it's `feGaussianBlur`, not `feGuassianBlur`

Answer (score 1):

I changed you svg filter and it works, but I don't know where is bug in your code.

Edit: ok, it was a typo :)

```css
body {
  filter: url('#goo')
}
.circle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #E63946;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.circle-1 {
  left: 12%;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle circle-1"></div>
<div class="circle circle-2"></div>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <defs>
    <filter id="goo">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="10" result="blur" />
      <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 19 -9" result="goo" />
      <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="goo" operator="atop"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>
```