How to implement smooth path join using SVG paths/figures?
I need to join SVG paths dynamically having the smooth joins (rendered red on the sample picture). Sample result below. Is there a way to achieve this without using any external libs? Ideally I need to be able to animate the circles while maintaining the joins smooth.


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42998065/playing-with-gooey-effect-with-svg

fascinating, thanks. @Robert give me a chance to earn my extra 2 points.
